# Pipe output out of through2

Tags: node.js, stream

I'm trying out through2 for the first time, and I'm running into a bit of trouble. I'm processing my data through a series of streams, and I want to pipe out of my transformation function.

The docs say I should be using `this.push` to get data out of my transform function, and then call the callback when I'm done, so I tried to do that using pipes (as that should do the same thing, right?), but I get a writeAfterEnd error. My code and the stacktrace are below, but I have no idea what to do. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Code -

```
function run(chunk, encoding, callback) {
    this.on("finish", function(){
        console.log("this finished")
        callback()
    })
    dataStream = new stream.Readable({objectMode: true});
    dataStream._read = function noop(){};
    dataStream.push(chunk);
    dataStream.pipe(sass()).pipe(this)
}

gulp.src("./web-src/scss/add_post.scss").pipe(through.obj(run)).on('data', function(chunk){console.log(chunk)})
```

Stacktrace -

```
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: write after end
    at writeAfterEnd (/Volumes/BackRoom/Dropbox/Timpani/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:198:12)
    at DestroyableTransform.Writable.write (/Volumes/BackRoom/Dropbox/Timpani/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:243:5)
    at write (/Volumes/BackRoom/Dropbox/Timpani/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:623:24)
    at flow (/Volumes/BackRoom/Dropbox/Timpani/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:632:7)
    at DestroyableTransform.pipeOnReadable (/Volumes/BackRoom/Dropbox/Timpani/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:664:5)
    at DestroyableTransform.emit (events.js:104:17)
    at emitReadable_ (/Volumes/BackRoom/Dropbox/Timpani/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:448:10)
    at emitReadable (/Volumes/BackRoom/Dropbox/Timpani/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:444:5)
    at readableAddChunk (/Volumes/BackRoom/Dropbox/Timpani/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:187:9)
    at DestroyableTransform.Readable.push (/Volumes/BackRoom/Dropbox/Timpani/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:149:10)
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you implementing a Stream or just using through2?

The [API docs warn against](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_push_chunk_encoding) stream consumers using .push().

Error: write after end could happen if chunk === null, which the "API for Stream Implementors" interprets as EOF.